# swift Custom Button extends UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to extend UIButton class to make my own radio button.

```
class UIRadioButton : UIButton {
        var checked = CheckedEnum.unchecked
        
        enum CheckedEnum{
            case checked , unchecked
        }
    }
```

It's inner class in Viewcontroller. But when I want to make this button sends the action to view Controller, as I usually do, it doesn't work. It's my button connections window:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDcWN.png)
And it's usually button connections window:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7WP8.png)

Comment: Show your code for *"sends the action to view Controller, as I usually do"* ... impossible to give you any help without seeing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should implement a delegate of your UITableViewCell and call its method when button receives touch event. Example:

```
protocol CellButtonDelegate: class {
    func cellButton(cell: UITableViewCell, didTouch button: UIButton)
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CellButtonDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton) {
          delegate?.cellButton(cell: self, didTouch button: sender)
    }
}
```

Then you make your view controller a delegate of each table view cell and handle this event.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
        // configure cell
        cell.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: CellButtonDelegate {
    func cellButton(cell: UITableViewCell, didTouch button: UIButton) {
        // handle button touch event, save indexPath of the cell to alter representation of table view after reloading data etc.
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.